# Trying to get an idea of decile system

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I was checking a Linkedin profile and I came across this statement in the “Grade” section. It’s a little confusing. It is as follows:

“Grade: gpa within the first decile”.

Is this statement correct? How’s interpreted?

Assuming that the GPA scale goes from 1 to 10 and not from 1 to 4, from the decile perspective we get the ordered set of grades:

*1, 2,…, 10*

Then, the first decile is: some value (x) is equal or smaller than the 10% or that the 90% is greater or equal than x. Taking this into account, wouldn’t we need a value in order to have the statement correct?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Context, please.